# How can I use 3D Touch in my app extension? (IOS 10)

Tags: ios, widget, 3dtouch, ios10

Can my widget be 3D pressed? I'm trying to write a Today Widget in IOS 10 but the official apple documentation gives nothing.

Comment: I think you will find you answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732641/can-you-use-3d-touch-on-widgets

Comment: I think it's suitable answer for ios 9. But on ios 10 things have changed, i hope it can be done :)

Comment: I hope you have read it somewhere that it can be done.

Comment: Did you finally find an answer ? :)

Comment: You cannot use 3D touch on your widget. Your app can only show your widget when the app icon is 3D touched